# Stuck in ASP.NET MVC DLL HELL, Razor Assembly issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm currently dealing with a problem on a ASP.NET MVC4 Application, I did a change of .NET Framework (from 4.5 to 4 then to 4.5 again) and it updated my NuGet packages so my Web.config is all messed up and i can't get rid of those errors that the YSOD shows me. Can you explain me a bit what can i do to correct those errors ?

Here's the error i get.

> [A]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection cannot be cast
>   to [B]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection. Type A
>   originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context
>   'Default' at location
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'.
>   Type B originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context
>   'Default' at location
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\5ccfcdb0\4d5a6f51\assembly\dl3\5f700272\1350df4e_ebe9ce01\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'.

Comment: Removed bad language.  Try and keep it civil, no matter how much you're banging your head against the desk :)

Comment: Try to run the command Add-BindingRedirect in the Nuget-prompt. Maybe a binding redirect can solve this.

Comment: Sorry for the language :)

Comment: Welcome to the club.

I've searched the entire solution for ANY instance of 2.0.0.0 and found NOTHING! There's not one single reference to ANY assembly with a 2 in it anywhere in my solution let alone System.Web.WebPages.Razor. I've also checked the actual version number of all the assemblies from the System.Web.WebPages namespace and they're all 3.0. 1. Uninstalled the MVC package from Nuget and reinstalled it. 2. Removed the assemblyBinding elements from Web.config. 3. Cleaned/rebuilt the solution. 4. Unloaded the solution and looked through the .proj file for any references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i solved my problem by myself.

I updated manually in the Web.config (from the Views Folder) the configuration to Version=3.0.0.0 and the version of the MvcWebRazorHostFactory (same file) to Version=5.0.0.0